# Pass an object into a soap request

Tags: c#

I want to send a list of objects using a soap request. Can I pass an object into a soap request, just as I would pass a string or an int?

```
    public class Customer
    {
     public string Name {set;get;}

    }

string field1 ="Hello";
List<Customer> p = new List<Customer>();
p.Add(new details() { Name ="XXXX" });
p.Add(new details() { Name ="YYYY" });

    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <Sample  xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <Stringfield1>field1</Stringfield1>
          <ObjectField>p</ObjectField> //Passing the List of CUstomer
        </Sample  >
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: Usually you have a proxy that takes care of the Soapy details for you, but if you are creating the XML yourself, you have to know how the service expects your Customer list to be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any object used as a parameter of a WCF function will be made part of the service contract wsdl and should be available on the client referencing the service. There are many attributes that can be used to control certain behaviors of the object and its members and how it is serialized and deserialized.